# Loop inside oval in Java

Tags: java

I need to examine each pixel inside an oval with Java.
For drawing, I am currently using:

```
drawOval(x,y,r*2,R*2).
```

However, since I need to get each pixel inside the Oval, I would like to create a loop that iterates inside it (assuming I have x,y,r and R). Is there any built in functionality for this purpose?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's [`Ellipse2D`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) implements the [`Shape`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface, so you can use one of the latter's `contains()` methods as required. It's also possible to render the [`Shape`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) into a [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and traverse its `WritableRaster`.

Answer (score 1):

simple canonical implicit equation for Oval is (with center 0; 0)

[image]

So yo can iterate throw all possible coordinates and check it using this equation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any built in functionality for this.

Let's go through this step by step.

Assuming that your ellipse's center is at `(0,0)`, one radius is `a`, other is `b`, the canonical equation is

```
x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1
```

Multiplying both sides with `a^2` and `b^2`, you get

```
x^2*b^2+y^2*a^2=a^2*b^2
```

Now, you must do a double for loop. `a` and `b` must be positive. Pseudocode:

```
for x = -a; x <= a; ++x:
   for y = -b; y <= b; ++y:
      if(x^2*b^2+y^2*a^2 <= a^2*b^2)
         // you're in your ellipse, do as you please
```

Of course, this will work only if center is at `(0,0)`, so if you want this algorithm to work, shift your points appropriately using translation. If you leave the center somewhere else, this algorithm will get messier.

*Note*: didn't test this. If somebody sees a mistake, please point it out.